# Publishing ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 Custom Toolbox to ArcGIS Server 10.6?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.6, service-definition

I am pretty new to this stuff.

I have a Custom Toolbox with python scripts that was created in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

I am upgrading to ArcGIS Desktop and Server 10.6 and trying to publish the Toolbox as a service.

I need a .sd file created but seem to hit a dead end on finding out how to do this.

I am able to open the .tbx in ArcCatalog but nothing shows up in the Results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does the tool run as expected in your ArcGIS Desktop session?

Comment: That is a good question.  I am installing this for a client and it seems like I need to execute the scripts first in order to publish.  From what I read anyways. I will have to ask them for the information needed to do so.

Comment: Yes. You would need to publish it from the "Results" tab in ArcMap.

Comment: The instructions on the website tell me to.  "If you want to publish a geoprocessing model or tool…" "…browse to a successful result of the model or tool in the Results window, right-click it, and choose Share As > Geoprocessing Service."

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and talking with ESRI I need to execute the tool in order to publish it and for it to show up in the "Results" tab.